# WebKit2.WebView (and Gnome Browser) doesn't play YouTube videos

Tags: webkit, gtk3, pygtk, pygobject, gnome-3

Inside a Python GTK+ 3 application I have a simple WebKit2.WebView (no customization) to display a set html string (no live browsing). The html contains a javascript lightbox with some youtube videos. When I open them, the youtube video box shows up but the content doesn't play and I get a black screen saying ("An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: ...").
Similar image found on the web: https://i.redd.it/gwqswatndiy11.png

**I then tried browsing the YouTube website with the Gnome Web browser (v 3.18.11 on Linux Mint 18.3) [based on WebKit] and the same problem occured with every video.**
Of course everything works with other browsers (Chromium and Firefox).
Moreover, everything works if I use WebKit1 instead of WebKit2 in my PyGtk+ 3 app.
**So I think the problem lies in the Webkit2 options configuration.**

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Here is an extract of my code. As you can see, I have already tried to set some options but nothing worked.
[Side note: `browser_settings.set_enable_media(True)` gives me the error `AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'set_enable_media'`; I don't understand why since in the documentation the method exists]

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('GtkSource', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GtkSource, GLib, WebKit2

self.webview = WebKit2.WebView.new()
browser_settings = self.webview.get_settings()
browser_settings.set_property('javascript-can-access-clipboard', bool(True))

# browser_context = self.webview.get_context()
# cookie_manager = browser_context.get_cookie_manager()
# cookie_manager.set_accept_policy(WebKit2.CookieAcceptPolicy.ALWAYS)
# browser_settings.set_enable_xss_auditor(False)
# browser_settings.set_allow_universal_access_from_file_urls(True)
# browser_settings.set_allow_file_access_from_file_urls(True)
# browser_settings.set_enable_media(True)
# browser_settings.set_enable_media_capabilities(True)
# browser_settings.set_enable_media_stream(True)
# browser_settings.set_enable_mediasource(True)
# browser_settings.set_media_playback_allows_inline(True)

self.webview.set_settings(browser_settings)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also couldn't initially play Youtube videos on Gnome Web (3.38.1) on Ubuntu Budgie 20.10. But I was able to make it work.

I checked Software, searched "gstreamer" and I see that most GStreamer codecs were already installed.

I was able to make Youtube videos work by installing "ffmpeg plugin for GStreamer" and "GStreamer WPEWebKit plugin".